# Shortest common cyclic superstring

Tags: substrings

The shortest common cyclic superstring problem is closely related to the shortest common superstring problem. The difference is that each of the strings in the input set may have an arbitrary rotation of the algorithm's choosing applied to them. By rotation I mean that for example `abcde -> deabc` would be a rotation by 2. Additionally any valid output may have an arbitrary rotation applied to it and it will still be considered valid (I don't think this helps much, though).

The classic greedy approximation algorithm for shortest common superstring runs in $O(m n^3)$ for a set of size $n$ where all the strings have at most length $m$. There are other approximation algorithms that run faster (even as fast as $O(mn \log \sigma)$ for an alphabet of size $\sigma$) but they are more complicated.

One obvious way to solve the shortest common cyclic superstring problem is to modify the greedy algorithm so that it rotates every pair of strings by every rotation. I believe this can result in an $O(m^2 n^3)$ algorithm. Is there a faster approximation algorithm for this problem that is about as complicated as the greedy algorithm for SCS? Hopefully with a similar approximation ratio, though I realize that there is probably little research on this subject.

Comment: So all strings must be rotated by the same value?

Comment: No, each string may be rotated by a different value.

Comment: Also isn’t shortest common superstring NP hard?

Comment: yes, I believe it was heavily implied by my mention of approximation ratio that I'm looking for an approximation algorithm